# Problemas en Ajax - Laravel error 404

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Me gustaría que me dijeran por favor que error estoy cometiendo ya que me sale esto y ya he visto muchos foros por favor se los pedire:

```
URL pedida:http://127.0.0.1:8000/{{ route('adm_us_agregar.add_data') }}
Código del estado: 404


$(document).on('click', '#agregarusuario', function() {

    var nombre = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].children[0].children[0].value;
    var apellido = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].children[1].children[0].value;
    var correo = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].children[2].children[0].value;
    var password = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].children[3].children[0].value;

    $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url:"{{ route('adm_us_agregar.add_data') }}",
    data:{nombre:nombre, apellido:apellido, correo:correo, password:password, _token:_token},
    success:function(data)
    {



        toastr.success('Registrado correctamente');

    }
   });

  });
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('adm_us_agregar/add_data', 'UsuariosAgregarController@add_data')->name('adm_us_agregar.add_data');
```

Esto es todo mi codigo no se que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: ¿Por qué eliminaste la pregunta anterior? te di una respuesta correcta.https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/258148/problema-en-ajax-laravel-error-404/258152#258152

Comment: cuando vi tu pregunta tenias `Route::post('adm_us_agregar/add_data', 'UsuariosAgregarController@add_data')` ahora ya lo cambiaste segun lo que respondi aun no funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Es simple tu ruta no tiene nombre, asi que solo tienes que definirlo:

```
Route::post('adm_us_agregar/add_data', 'UsuariosAgregarController@add_data')->name('adm_us_agregar.add_data');
```

Espero que eso solucione tu error.

Answer (score 0):

El error consiste en que al ser un archivo js externo estás fuera del framework Laravel, por lo cual no funcionan las etiquetas de Blade.

Soluciones:

1. Escribir directamente la ruta en el archivo externo de JavaScript.
2. Utilizar paquetes externos como laroute: https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute
3. Hay otras soluciones pero pueden ser más engorrosas y depende ya de la magnitud del proyecto.